# Try to filter ListView.builder inside StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm newbie in Flutter and I'm  trying to develop an app, so nom have a trouble with how to show a filtered ListView.builder

This is the widget code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

print('Favorites');
return Container(
  color: AppColors.hexToColor('F0F4F5'),
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      HeaderCity(),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
          child: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder<CoworkingState>(
                stream: Provider.coworkingBlocOf(context).streamCoworkingState,
                initialData: CoworkingState(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CoworkingState> snapshot) {
                  return (snapshot.data.isLoading)
                      ? CustomCircularLoader()                          
                      : ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            if (snapshot.data.coworking.any((isFavorite) => true)){
                              return CoworkingCellDetail(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Provider.coworkingBlocOf(context)
                                      .selectCoworking(coworking: snapshot.data.coworking[index]);
                                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                                    changeRoute(context, Routes.coworkDetail, false);
                                  });
                                },
                                isFavorite: snapshot.data.coworking[index].isFavorite,
                                name: snapshot.data.coworking[index].name,
                                adress: snapshot.data.coworking[index].address,
                                phone: snapshot.data.coworking[index].phone,
                                hour: snapshot.data.coworking[index].openingHours,
                                urlImages: snapshot.data.coworking[index].imagesUrl,
                                onFavoriteTap: () {
                                  Provider.coworkingBlocOf(context).removeFavorite(snapshot.data.coworking[index].id);
                                }
                              );
                            } return null; 
                          },
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.coworking.length,
                        );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

So now this  are returning a complete list and I only want to show items with `isFavorite = true`

Comment: Do you really need a Stream? Could it be done using a Future? Any how... before sending your data over the Stream, you can apply filters over your list. The operator in Dart is called "where".

Answer (score 0):

You are not if condition is not working correctly.

You are returning true for each and every case that’s why it is adding all the items.

Try Following one:

```
...
if (snapshot.data.coworking.any((isFavorite) => isFavorite)){ //here it return true if isFavorite is true and if isFavorite is false then it will return false.
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your isFavorite datatype is bool, if it is a String change the below if statement to this snapshot.data.coworking[index].isFavorite.toString() == "true"

```
if(snapshot.data.coworking[index].isFavorite){
       return CoworkingCellDetail(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Provider.coworkingBlocOf(context)
                                      .selectCoworking(coworking: snapshot.data.coworking[index]);
                                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                                    changeRoute(context, Routes.coworkDetail, false);
                                  });
                                },
                                isFavorite: snapshot.data.coworking[index].isFavorite,
                                name: snapshot.data.coworking[index].name,
                                adress: snapshot.data.coworking[index].address,
                                phone: snapshot.data.coworking[index].phone,
                                hour: snapshot.data.coworking[index].openingHours,
                                urlImages: snapshot.data.coworking[index].imagesUrl,
                                onFavoriteTap: () {
                                  Provider.coworkingBlocOf(context).removeFavorite(snapshot.data.coworking[index].id);
                                }
                              );
    }
```